# Power BI Refresh

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am using SQL Server Database for my Power BI reports using import , is there any way to refresh the reports every hour (without using direct query)?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Raj, If you want an auto refresh you should use Power BI Services (See MatRic Answer). If you want this option in Power BI Desktop, it's not yet available. But you can vote for this feature: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/15507999-auto-refresh-data-in-power-bi-desktop

Answer (score 1):

you can go on Power BI Services, on your dataset (the one related to your DB) and schedule a refresh and then, add every hour of the day in you scheduled refresh. I'm totally aware that it is not the best option but it is working. Let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to have a job on your SQL server that runs every hour and saves the data, for the BI, to a table. Then the BI would not have to do any processing, rather it would just read (i.e. Direct Query) the latest data from a table. That should be a lot faster than running the query, in Direct Query, every time.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides these options:

1. Configure refresh in Power BI - with Pro license you can refresh up to 8x per day. With Premium - it's 48x per day.
2. Use Power Automate to trigger the refresh

Since Power Automate can trigger a flow based on a large number of factors - this opens a lot of possibilities. It appears you could schedule a refresh as often as you like - it will just cost you "flows" - the pricing on which I don't understand.

If your DB refresh can finish with an email being sent to you - you could then trigger the flow based on receiving that email. Here's a video of how to set up that flow: https://youtu.be/QFvMQ-FLVBI

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73518089/power-automate-wait-till-power-bi-dataset-refresh-completes-fails) discusses how the request to trigger the refresh does NOT wait for the refresh to complete -- and @Dani U makes a strong recommendation that seems like wisdom - but I'm not sure yet:

> Power BI's lack of admin and monitoring tooling is by far its biggest
> shortcoming--especially surrounding refresh management. The sooner you
> realize you will not get out of it what you want and just accept that
> you're going to have to roll your own, the sooner you'll get what you
> need.

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry to say but the schedule refresh functionality is only present in your Power BI Service and not in Power BI Desktop. If you want to know how to implement Schedule Refresh in Power BI Service I will provide you the solution. Please revert back and I have written one blog too. You can go through this link.
[Visit this link](https://www.loginworks.com/blogs/how-to-configure-schedule-refresh-in-power-bi-reports/)